# Find data in table_1 and return it's primary key to table_2 - PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql, primary-key

In my postgresql database I have a table "countries":

```
| primary key | country_name|
```

And I have a csv file:

```
| primary_key | person_name | person's country |
```

I want to import this csv to my DB to the new table "people" and I want to automatically search person's country in the table "countries" and return it's primary key to the 4th new column of the table "people".

Can someone help with the script please?

UPDATE:
I'm now trying sir Zeki told me:

```
update people set country_id = (select id from countries where countries.country_name = people.country_name)
```

works fine, but the problem is that countries_id column remains empty. Even after I refresh the table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by adding the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Import the new table into postgres, add a fourth column, and then run something like:

```
update people set country_id = (select id from countries where countries.country_name = people.country_name)
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply.
I did it and pgAdmin told me that "Query returned successfully: 1154 rows affected, 69 ms execution time." 
I refreshed the table but there arnt any changes, column country_id is still empty -(